# Improving chemfig drawing

Tags: chemfig

As a learning exercise I have been trying to replicate the structure of LSD using chemfig. I've taken [this figure](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/LSD-2D-skeletal-formula-and-3D-models.png) for reference.

My best effort so far has been this...

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Package for chemical equation typesetting
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(=(*5(-N-=(*6(--([:-30]<H)(*6(-N(-)--([:120]<:H)(-([:30]=O)([::60]-N([:180]-[::45]-)([:60]-[:10]-)))-=-))---))--))-=-=-)}
\end{document}
```

which produces ...

[image]

I have not been able to figure out how to create the proper triple ring nor have I gotten a proper understanding of the bond angles on the two chains off the N.

I would certainly appreciate any and all advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, although I admit I'm not very expert with `chemfig`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % Package for chemical equation typesetting
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6(=(-[:-70]N-[:0]=[:70])-(*6(---(*6(([:90]<H)-
N(-[:-30]CH_3)--(-[:90](=[:30]O)-[:145]N(-[:210]-[:150])
(--[:150]))([:145]<:H)-=))---))=-=-)} 
\end{document}
```